# Selenium IDE - Script doesn't load overlay

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE with Firefox.
The idea is to fill a form and click the button "Save", which loads an overlay that contains a popup with an "OK" button.
The script runs ok but, when it clicks the Save button, the overlay doesn't load.

If I do it manually or pressing X over the selenium command, everything works, the form is saved.
I have a problem only with the script.

The weirdest thing is that the entire system has this behavior with all the forms, and only the Save button of this form doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I already tried combinations with pause, all the "click" commands, fireEvent, xPath, CSS, class (doesn't have ID or Name) etc... 
But as it works when I press X over the selenium command, I don't believe that the locator is the problem.

I was told that the plugin jAlert is used.

Here's the code of the button (Salvar = Save).
The overlay should appear after the "click | link=Salvar" command.

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Salvar</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=popup_ok</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any link or sample code?

Comment: I edited the post and put the code there =)

Comment: @Cindy did you find solution to this issue?

Comment: @Rads No, but after a new package, Selenium somehow started to show the overlay.